# How to change JavaScript alert into bootstrap modal in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, bootstrap-modal, cakephp-3.0

I have this code which deletes the students according to the `student_id`. But it displays a JavaScript alert box to confirm whether I want to delete the student.

I want a Bootstrap modal box which asks whether I want to delete the student and then deletes the student which matches the id when I click on Yes.
The below code gives a JavaScript alert. I want a bootstrap modal.

```
<?= $this->Html->image('webroot/img/delete.png', [
    'alt' => 'Delete',
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Students', 'action' => 'delete', $student->id]
]) ?>
```

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui or similar?

Comment: No. I am not using anything like that.. just cakePHP 3 and bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo $this->Html->link(
     $this->Html->image('webroot/img/delete.png', ["alt" => "Delete"]),
     ['controller' => 'Students', 'action' => 'delete', $student->id],
     [
      'confirm' => 'Are you sure you wish to delete this item?',
      'escape' => false
     ]
);
```

Comment: This just gives JavaScript alert and not a bootstrap modal